# How to validate react-multiselect using Yup validation schema

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

if multiselect is empty this is not showing the validation message as 'Product is required' How can I validate this field.

**This is the validation schema**

```
validationSchema={
         Yup.object().shape({
         productID: Yup.string().required('Product is required').min('1','Product is required') //minimum value should be greater than 0 ,
         collectionTypeID: Yup.string().max(255).required('Collection Type is required'),
          })
        }
```

**This is multiselect component**

```
<MultiSelect
  id="productID"
  name="productID"
  key={clear}
  error={Boolean(touched.productID && errors.productID)}
  fullWidth
  helperText={touched.productID && errors.productID}
  variant="outlined"
  placeholder={"--Select Product--"}
  closeOnSelect={true}
  clearable={true}
  onChange={(e) => {
  handleOnchange(e)
  productSelectOnChange(e)
  }}
  options={options}
  >
</MultiSelect>
```

**This is the sample of my array data (inside the option array)**

```
0
: 
{label: 'Bought Leaf', value: 1}
1
: 
{label: 'Rubber', value: 2}
2
: 
{label: 'coffee', value: 3}
3
: 
{label: 'cashew', value: 4}
```

I want to validate this multiselect field if it is empty. need to display validation message as 'Product is required'. I think multiselect not passing the ref but I have no idea how to manually handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Your case productId will be object array since it is a multi select

Try to change your schema like below

```
productID: Yup.array()
  .of(
    Yup.object({
      value: Yup.string(),
    }),
  )
  .min(1, 'Product is required')
  .required('Product is required');
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried answer that's you provided  but it not show the validation error message.

Comment: Can you try to put your code into JSfiddle or someother tool so i can check